# Wordpress list posts by modified date

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I did try the following code for get all wordpress post from modified date but I'm not able to get post from modified date. By using following code I'm getting data by `post_date` rather then `post_modified`. I have post by `25-12-2017` `modified date` and its `post date` was 23-12-2017. I want get data by post modified date.

Thank you

**first code:**

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $Limit,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'offset' => ($Page - 1) * $Limit,
    'year'=>date('Y'),
    'monthnum'=>date('m'),
    'day'=> 25,
    'order'=> 'DESC',
);
?>
```

**Second code:**

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $Limit,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'offset' => ($Page - 1) * $Limit,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => "December 24, 2017",            
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't think by default WordPress have this feature, but you can achieve this
>   by [`posts_where`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) filter.

Here is a sample code:

Write this in your `functions.php` file

```
function scopePostModifiedDate($sql)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $sql .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND DATE($wpdb->posts.post_modified) >= %s ", '2017-12-25');
    return $sql;
}
```

And this code whenever you need:

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'scopePostModifiedDate');

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $Limit,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'offset' => ($Page - 1) * $Limit,
//    'date_query' => array(
//        array(
//            'after'     => "December 24, 2017",            
//        ),
//    ),
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter('posts_where', 'scopePostModifiedDate');
//print_r($custom_query->request); //print SQL query
```

Refrence:

- https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/trying-to-create-custom-where-clause
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48677/how-to-pass-external-variables-to-filters-actions